# How do I use subclasses in a factory subclass to override abstract class in a superclass factory?

Tags: java, subclassing, abstract-factory

I am writing a program that needs to do CRUD operations with sub-classes of an abstract object `Assignment`. I have factories to do the CRUD operations, but I am having a problem overriding the methods.

```
public abstract class Assignment {
    protected Integer id = null;
    protected String name = null;
    public Assignment() {}
    public Assignment(Assignment original) { // code here to clone }
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

a concrete assignment

```
public class DCONAssignment extends Assignment {
    protected Integer amount = null;
    protected String type = null;
    public DCONAssignment() {}
    public DCONAssignment(DCONAssignment original) { // code here to clone }
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

abstract factory

```
public abstract class AssignmentProcessor {
    public abstract Assignment loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId);
//  public abstract boolean saveAssignment(Assignment assignment); // option 1
//  public abstract boolean saveAssignment(<? extends Assignment> assignment); // option 2 // This says "abstract methods do not specify a body"
//  public <T extends Assignment> boolean saveAssignment(T assignment) { //option 3
    public boolean saveAssignment(Assignment assignment) { //option 4
        return false;
    }
    protected Assignment loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId, Class<? extends Assignment> clazz) {
        Assignment assignment = null;
        try {
            assignment = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BurstAssignment burstAssignment = null; // load assignmnet from db
        assignment.setId(burstAssignment.getId());

        return assignment;
    }
}
```

and concrete factory

```
public class DCONAssignmentProcessor extends AssignmentProcessor {
    @Override
    public DCONAssignment loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId) {
        DCONAssignment assignment = (DCONAssignment) loadAssignment(assignmentId, DCONAssignment.class);
        return assignment;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean saveAssignment(DCONAssignment assignment) { // eclipse says I need to override a method with options 1, 3 and 4
        return false;
    }
}
```

In conclusion, the abstract factory handles some of the heavy lifting for loading an Assignment. The concrete factories handle details for their particular implementation of the Assignment class. The problem is overriding the  abstract methods with concrete parameters. So the question is, how can I specify a method in the abstract factory and override it with a concrete parameter in the concrete factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem the solution was to make the abstract factory generic

```
public abstract class AssignmentProcessor<T extends Assignment>  {
    public abstract T loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId);
    public boolean saveAssignment(T assignment) {
        return false;
    }
    protected Assignment loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId, Class<T> clazz) {
        Assignment assignment = null;
        try {
            assignment = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BurstAssignment burstAssignment = SessionHelper.getSession().getBurstAssignment(assignmentId);
        assignment.setId(burstAssignment.getId());
        return assignment;
    }
}
```

concrete factory

```
public class DarfAssignmentProcessor extends AssignmentProcessor<DarfAssignment> {
    @Override
    public DarfAssignment loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId) {
        DarfAssignment assignment = (DarfAssignment) loadAssignment(assignmentId, DarfAssignment.class);
        return assignment;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean saveAssignment(DarfAssignment assignment) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `public boolean saveAssignment(T assignment) { return false; }` in your base class, you could make the saveAssignment abstract `public abstract boolean saveAssignment(T assignment);` which would require the derived class to provide an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

JSYK: You don't have to override the `getId`, `setId`, `getName` and `setName` methods in `DCONAssignment`.  They get inherited from the base class, and you aren't actually changing them.

---

When you use `@Override`, you are telling the compiler that you *intend* the method you are creating to replace a method in the parent class with the new method.  This means you *expect* the parent class to have a method with the same name and signature.  If the compiler looks and can't find a the method with the same name and signature, generates an error.  Eclipse takes the error, examines your code, and is offering you suggestions on how to fix the issue.

Option 1: `public abstract boolean saveAssignment(Assignment assignment);`

The base class defines a method with an `Assignment` argument.  A `DCONAssignment` is-a `Assignment`, so you can simply define the `saveAssignment` method in the derived class to accept an `Assignment`, and pass in the `DCONAssignment` object.

To function properly, you'll have to cast in the derived method:

```
@Override
public boolean saveAssignment(Assignment assignment) {
    if (assignment instanceof DCONAssignment)) {
        DCONAssignment da = (DCONAssignment) assignment;
        // ... save da 
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected DCONAssignment");
    }
}
```

Option 2: `public abstract boolean saveAssignment(<? extends Assignment> assignment);`

Here, your base class's method explicitly states it will accept any class which extends `Assignment`.  You would override this in your derived class, and, again, check the actual class to verify it is given the correct class.

```
@Override
public boolean saveAssignment(<? extends Assignment> assignment) {
    if (assignment instanceof DCONAssignment) {
        DCONAssignment da = (DCONAssignment) assignment;
        // ... save da 
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected DCONAssignment");
    }
}
```

Option 3: `public <T extends Assignment> boolean saveAssignment(T assignment)`

Again, this is the same as option 2, but explicitly giving the template type the name `T`.

Option 4: looks identical to Option 1, except for whether the method is declared abstract (no method body) or not in the base class.

---

The simplest fix is to use the Option 1 approach, use `instanceof` to check if the argument is actually the expected type, and cast.

A more structured approach would be to declare your factory class to be template based.

```
public abstract class AssignmentProcessor<T extends Assignment> {
    public abstract T loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId);
    public abstract boolean saveAssignment(T assignment);
}
```

Then you can declare your derived processor with the expected type:

```
public class DCONAssignmentProcessor extends AssignmentProcessor<DCONAssignment> {
    @Override
    public DCONAssignment loadAssignment(Integer assignmentId) {
        // Your load code
    }
    @Override
    public boolean saveAssignment(DCONAssignment assignment) {
        // Your save code
    }
}
```

The abstract factory can implement any common methods to do the heavy lifting as before.